# Conditional Configuration of Struct Member and Attribute

Tags: rust

I have a feature called `backend` for my crate called `shared`. I have a struct in `shared/cart_items.rs` as follows:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use chrono::Duration;
use serde_with::serde_as;
use serde_with::DurationSeconds;
use uuid::Uuid;

#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
use scylla::{FromRow, ValueList};
#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
use scylla::frame::value::Timestamp;
#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
use crate::extensions::scylla::frame::value::timestamp::TimestampDef; //Code I wrote to handle Timestamps for Scylla
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "backend", derive(FromRow, ValueList))]
pub struct CartItem
{
    pub id              :   Uuid,
    
    pub service_name                :   String,

    //#[cfg_attr(feature = "backend", serde(with = "TimestampDef"))]
    #[cfg(feature = "backend")]
    #[cfg_attr(feature="backend", serde(with = "TimestampDef"))]
    pub delivery_date               :   Timestamp,

    #[cfg(not(feature = "backend"))]
    #[cfg_attr(not(feature="backend"), serde_as(as = "DurationSeconds<i64>"))]
    pub delivery_date               :   Duration,

    pub additional_instructions     :   String,
}
```

The problem is that on compilation with the `backend` feature DISABLED I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `chrono::Duration: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> shared/cart_items.rs:40:25
     |
40   |     pub delivery_date                :    Duration,
     |                                           ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `chrono::Duration`
     |
```

Even though upon macro expansion I would expect the following is what rust has:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use chrono::Duration;
use serde_with::serde_as;
use serde_with::DurationSeconds;
use uuid::Uuid;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct CartItem
{
    pub id              :   Uuid,
    
    pub service_name                :   String,

    #[serde_as(as = "DurationSeconds<i64>"))]
    pub delivery_date               :   Duration,

    pub additional_instructions     :   String,
}
```

How do I get this to work as intended. For context, this is a shared library between the frontend and backend and `scylla` CANNOT be imported for the frontend and for the backend it can which is why the struct needs to use `TimestampDef` and `Timestamp` as well as the `Duration` from `chrono`.

Comment: do you have the `serde` feature turned on for chrono?

Comment: Yes. Serde is enabled. I figured out the solution today and will be posting the full answer. Avoids having to make duplicate structs as well.

Comment: Note that what are you doing is not recommended at all, as [features should be additive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-unification).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works as intended:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use chrono::Duration;
use serde_with::serde_as;
use serde_with::DurationSeconds;
use uuid::Uuid;

#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
use scylla::{FromRow, ValueList};
#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
use scylla::frame::value::Timestamp;
#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
use crate::extensions::scylla::frame::value::timestamp::TimestampDef; //Code I wrote to handle Timestamps for Scylla
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "backend", derive(FromRow, ValueList))]
pub struct CartItem
{
    pub id              :   Uuid,
    
    pub service_name                :   String,

    #[cfg(feature = "backend")]
    #[serde(with = "TimestampDef")]
    pub delivery_date               :   Timestamp,

    #[cfg(not(feature = "backend"))]
    #[serde_as(as = "DurationSeconds<i64>")]
    pub delivery_date               :   Duration,

    pub additional_instructions     :   String,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code minified:

```rust
use chrono::Duration;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_with::{serde_as, DurationSeconds};

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct CartItem {
    #[cfg(not(feature = "backend"))]
    #[cfg_attr(not(feature="backend"), serde_as(as = "DurationSeconds<i64>"))]
    pub delivery_date: Duration,
}
```

Now the problem is, that the outer `#[serde_as]` is evaluated before the inner `#[cfg_attr(..., serde_as(...))]` is (can be seen by [expanding the macros](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/ihqdnz), observe the outermost `#[serde_as]` is already gone, while the field still has `#[serde_as(...)]`).

You can work around that by having 2 separate definitions of your struct:

```rust
#[cfg(not(feature = "backend"))]
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct CartItem {
    pub service_name: String,

    #[serde_as(as = "DurationSeconds<i64>")]
    pub delivery_date: Duration,
}

#[cfg(feature = "backend")]
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct CartItem {
    #[serde(with = "TimestampDef")]
    pub delivery_date: Timestamp,
}
```